# VB Excel, How to make a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

here is what i want:

Assume I have 2 ranges of data A and B. B is calculated from a series of calculation included values of range A. I want a loop of 20 times to put B into A and calculate B again. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple VBA loop that creates a 20 x 20 matrix. It will help you understand looping with two number ranges.

```
Sub looptutorial()   
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select
For b = 1 To 20        
    For a = 1 To 20  
    Cells(a, b).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = a * b  
    Next a           
Next b    
End Sub
```

Comment: 'Select' should be avoided in VBA.

Comment: @brettdj yes thanks for the comment. I wanted to make it intuitive how the code worked when the op stepped through the code. I agree with you.